# Triangle of asterisks in Python

Tags: python

I need to create a triangle with asterisk with a single function but i need to make them this way:

```
*****
****
***
**
*
**
***
****
*****
```

So far I have this but I ended up in a endless loop.

```
def triangle (n):
    i = 0
    x = n + 1
    while i<n:
        print ("*"*(x))
        x = x - 1
        i=i+1
        if i == n:
            while i != 0:
                print ("*"*(x))
                x = x + 1
                i=i-1
    return ("*")

n=int(input("How many * would you like to see?"))
```

Comment: The problem is cause once `i += 1` becames `i==n` the it enters the if statement and reduces `i`. The next time `while i<n` checks `i` is less than `n`

Answer (score 1):

You could also just use two of Python's `range()` functions to do this as follows:

```
for length in range(5, 0, -1) + range(2, 6):
    print '*' * length
```

Or using Python 3:

```
for length in list(range(5, 0, -1)) + list(range(2, 6)):
    print('*' * length)
```

So as a function you would have:

```
def triangle(n):
    for length in list(range(n, 0, -1)) + list(range(2, n+1)):
        print('*' * length)

n = int(input("How many * would you like to see? "))
triangle(n)
```

Comment: For python 3 it may be cleaner to use `itertools.chain`: `from itertools import chain` and then `for length in chain(range(n,0,-1), range(2,n+1)):` (also note the +1 otherwise the bottom of the pyramid stops a line early).

Comment: Thank, last edit accidental removed the wrong +1.  Also I was trying not to use any imports.

Comment: One loop: `for i in range(-n+1,n): print('x'*(abs(i)+1))` :^)